# Xeon X5355 vs. Xeon E5405

Tags: central-processing-unit, xeon

The X5355 has less cache and a higher TDP but it has a higher clock speed and it's a higher end Clovertown whereas the 5405 is an entry level Harpertown. If you were to plop two of these into a server which ones would provide more processing power? Also would a single X3460 beat both of the previous solution?

I'm looking at these for a machine that will host game servers.

Comment: "which ones would provide more processing power" - depends on what you're doing. Are you doing something that requires a metric crapload of L2 cache, or something that needs more raw cycles per second?

Comment: I would say raw cycles per second would be more beneficial for game servers. In that sense it would seem that the X5355 would be better but I'm just not sure how the architectural differences between Clovertown and Harpertown will change things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the benchmark results at [spec.org](http://spec.org).  You can find ratings for many computer systems for a number of different benchmarks, depending on your needs.  For those two processors and your intended use as a game server, I would consider the CPU2006 results for integer speed and throughput.  For both those benchmarks, it appears that the E5405 is about 18% faster than the X5355.